# Java: Modify nested property from JSON file and keep rest of file content intact, comments specifically

Tags: java, json

Is it possible to update a nested property in a JSON file programmatically using Java, while preserving the rest of content intact (comments and formatting particularly), external libraries are totally fine.

Comment: I think the safest way is to read Json file, store it to Object (like `JSONObject`), update object and save back to file. With this approach you will avoid basic errors with JSON validation.

Comment: Yes but that will discard comments.

Comment: Well,  I don't think you can have an comment in Json file. Lokks like its not a json :)

Comment: Yes you can, all major editors allow comments in json, it's just not standard :)

Comment: You could try to achieve this with a regex. It would probably get pretty ugly but should work. All libraries will probably discard comments as they are supposed to be ignored. Another way to do the parsing would be to write a parser yourself. If you want to go down this road you could look at parser generators like ANTLR (I think there should be JSON grammars available somewhere for most parser generators).

Comment: I did think about the regex approach but wanted to make sure there's no clean alternative. Definitely don't wanna go for creating a parser myself. I hope I won't be forced to use a regex. Thanks for suggestions :)